# typescript assign specific coordinate to x and y

Tags: arrays, loops, typescript

I am trying to map my obstacles with a single object.

I was using random to randomly scatter it around the map, now I want to hard code the X & Y coordinate with an array of numbers, but typescript only use last value of the loop for X coordinate. How do I assign specific numbers to each obstacle?

**random generate**

```
module objects {
    export class Obstacles extends objects.GameObject {
        public Start():void {

            this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (640) - this.width) + this.halfWidth;
            this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (480) - this.width) + this.halfWidth;
            console.log("x " + this.x);
            console.log("y " + this.y);

  }
}
```

[image]

**specify x value with array**

```
private _obstX: number [] = [200, 250, 300, 350, 400];

public Start():void {

      for (let count = 0; count < this._obstX.length; count++) {
          this.x = this._obstX[count];
      }

      this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (480) - this.width) + this.halfWidth;
      console.log("x " + this.x);
      console.log("y " + this.y);

  }
```

[image]

Only one x value is assigned, the other x value in the array is ignored

**Code in main file**

```
private _obstPlanes: objects.Obstacles[];
private _obstNum: number;

public Start(): void {
  this._obstPlanes = new Array<objects.Obstacles>();
  this._obstNum = 5;


  for (let count = 0; count < this._obstNum; count++) {
    this._obstPlanes[count] = new objects.Obstacles(this.assetManager);
  }
}
public Main(): void {
  this._obstPlanes.forEach(obstPlane => {
      this.addChild(obstPlane);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you instantiate a new `Obstacles` object, you loop through your array `_obstX` setting the `x` property to the nth value from your array.  All your `Obstacles` have an `x` value of 400 because the last iteration of the `for` loop sets `this.x` to the last value in the array.

I would move the `_obstX` array to the main file, and add an `x` parameter/property to your `Obstacles` constructor.  I'm not sure how you're constructor looks right now, but could be something like:

```
constructor(private assetManager: AssetManger, private x: number) {}
```

Then call the constructor with:

```
new objects.Obstacles(this.assetManager, _obstX.shift())
```

This will send the first element in `_obstX` to the constructor, and remove that value from the array.  As you create each `Obstacles` object, it will have the next `x` value from the array.

Comment: You are right, it only takes the last value of the loop, I followed your advice, and then in the constructor, I set `this.x = x`, now it is working properly.